# Using a "copy always" file in a dll, which is referenced by an ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a component. This component has a file called myfile.txt under folder data. I want this file to appear in the data folder in the every complied console application or published ASP.NET webapplication under root/data/myfile.txt that references this component.

Now, in Visual Studio, I can set the file to "Copy Always", which is good for console applications, but for ASP.NET published websites, it will go to root/bin/data/myfile.txt

How to make this myfile.txt to appear always under the released application's  root/data/myfile.txt, regardless if it's a console application or an ASP.NET webapplication?

What Visual Studio setting should I use for this file?

(I have full access to everything: the applications and the component too)

Comment: are you dealing with an ASP.NET website or a web application??

Comment: Since the whole project is compiled into a single dll, I guess it's a web application.

Comment: I've updated my awnswer,did you have any luck fixing your issue?

Comment: We dropped the idea of depending on Visual Studio "magic" and just manually put the file at the same place for every environment. I checked this Advanced Precompile Settings, but saw no option to ignore certain non-dll files from certain assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

take a look to the Advanced Precompile Settings dialog box lets you specify how a web application is precompiled or assemblies are merged.

To access this dialog

- In Visual Studio, open a web application project.
- Right click the project name in Solution Explorer, and then choose Publish.
- Select the Settings tab. Expand File Publish Options, and then select
  Precompile during publishing.

take a look to the this [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) maybe that helps